# Meteor JS: Dynamic Layout Template

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, coffeescript, iron-router

I want to make the layout template dynamic. The value of the layout template would be fetch in the server using a Meteor.call 'getLayoutTemplate'. Where shall I put the Meteor.call? And it should wait until it fetches the value of the Meteor.call. Any ideas?

```
Router.configure
  layoutTemplate: ????
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'
```

Comment: My first idea would be, to put it into a Session-Variable.

Comment: @DanielBudick That would nice idea. But where shall I put the Meteor.call? because the value of that session variable will be coming from the server  (Meteor.call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the method call in a `onAfterAction` hook and then set the `layoutTemplate` depending on the call's result:

```
Router.route('/route', {
  name: 'route',
  onAfterAction: function() {
    var routerInstance = this;
    Meteor.call('method', function(error, result) {
      routerInstance.layoutTemplate = result;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but onAfterAction does get fired

Comment: I just tried it in an existing project and it works. Do you have any error message in the console?

Comment: I made a gist https://gist.github.com/ccfiel/6e73182113224118cdba. No error in Console. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your server method returning something? Also be careful about asynchronous things in the server method, because you want an answer on the client so you need to return something from the server.